# Произведение элементов массива

Tags: c++

Как найти произведение элементов массива, которые расположены между максимальным и минимальным элементами?

Comment: А если все элементы равны? А если минимальных элементов много?

Comment: @VladD, это второй этап, не спешите, мы еще с Вами увидим эти вопросы ))))

Comment: @VladD может сразу ссылку на вопросы о длинном умножении чисел? А то не влезет в __int128

Comment: @pavel: Ну ладно вам новичков пугать длинной арифметикой :) Тут проблема в декомпозиции задачи.

Comment: @VladD хотел бы испугать, написал бы на CUDA решение, не факт что без ошибок но это детали...

Comment: @pavel: Злой вы! :)

Comment: @pavel: А кстати, есть ли однопроходное решение? И ещё O(1) по дополнительной памяти?

Comment: @VladD да. Но на месте преподавателя, читать это я лично не хотел бы.

Comment: @pavel: Хм. Нужно произведение от минимума до текущего элемента, текущее произведение от текущего минимума до кекущего максимума, ну и сами текущий минимум и текущий максимум. Вроде достаточно. Если так прокатит, можно вполне написать читабельно.

Comment: @VladD http://ideone.com/WJCpts первый прототип на коленке.

Comment: @pavel: Угу, но вроде бы нужно ещё пару переменных на случай, если максимум идёт перед минимумом?

Comment: @Даша Новикова  Максимальных и минимальных элементов может быть много. Более того диапазон между максимальным и минимальным элементами может отличаться от диапазона между минимальным и максимальным элементами. Поэтому уточните условия задачи. Например, задача может звучать так: найти произведение элементов в диапазоне от первого минимального до последнего максимального элемента, или как-нибудь по-другому.

Answer (score 0):

Решение не лучшее, далеко не лучшее, но опробуйте:

```
int data[] = { 2, 4, 5, 2, -3, 5, 2, 33, 5, 3, -45, 2 };

    std::pair<int *, int *> pr = std::minmax_element( std::begin( data ), std::end( data ) );

    if( std::distance( std::begin( data ), pr.second ) < std::distance( std::begin( data ), pr.first ) )
        std::swap( pr.first, pr.second );

    if( pr.first != pr.second && ++pr.first != pr.second )
    {
        int res = std::accumulate( pr.first, pr.second, 1, std::multiplies<int>() );
    }
```

Comment: `if (pr.second < pr.first)`, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy, там ведь префиксный оператор ++, он ведь там не просто так )

Comment: Я вообще-то хотел вот это заменить: `if( std::distance( std::begin( data ), pr.second ) < std::distance( std::begin( data ), pr.first ) )`, а не второе условие.

Comment: Впрочем, во втором же тоже можно `if(++pr.first < pr.second)`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, извиняюсь, не правильно Вас понял. Возможно здесь это будет приемлемо, просто даже не знаю, норм так адреса сравнивать ?

Comment: @Qwertiy, самому интересно стало - а если это будет std::vector ? Насколько я помню, этот парень может хранить элементы в памяти не в линейном порядке.

Comment: А почему не нормально? Вроде, вектор уже обязали хранить подряд, не? Хотя, можно отдельным вопросом всё это спросить :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, если честно - не слышал, но Вы же понимаете, что даже если и обязали - не значит реализовали ))

Comment: Да он везде так был реализован, всегда. По крайней мере, не знаю где бы он хранился не так.

Comment: @Qwertiy, кажется читал об это то ли в статье Мейерса, то ли Саттера. То ли это уже действительно не актуально, то ли.. )) Вообщем, найду - скину линк.

Comment: Код - шило! На наборе int data[] = { -1, 1, 1, 2, 2, -1, 1, 2, 2, -1} выводит -8, и с какого это перепугу? Максимальное "2", минимальное "-1", подходит только последовательность  "2,2,-1", и то, если только считать, что мин/макс могут входить, а иначе - результат должен быть нулевой.

Comment: @Majestio, ахахаха)) бомбиииит )) а кто Вам сказал, что он идеален ? Если Вы очень сильно постараетесь (не ради меня, конечно, но найдите причину), и откроете свои глаза пошире, то Вы увидите, что в самом начале написано - _решение.не.лучшее_, и я об этом предупредил сразу. А Вам, раз уж Вы напомнили о себе внеочердной раз, напомню - сортировку использовать неуместно.

Comment: Уместно править вопрос ТС'а так, чтобы он стал хоть чуток определеннее. А то из воды сделали воду, и своей водой залили.

Comment: @Majestio, повторяю последний раз - я только сделал Вам замечание, и как оказалось, на замечания Вы реагируете крайне неадекватно. Поэтому и здесь предлагаю прекратить этот бессмысленный диалог.

Comment: На опубликованный мною код - вы реагируете крайне неадекватно, разразившись серией "замечаний"... Обратите внимание на себя - вы же для себя важнее чем я.

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение порождает и другие вопросы, но тем не менее.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    std::cout << "n = ";
    std::cin >> n;
    int* mass = new int[n];
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    std::cin >> mass[i];
    int max = 0, min = 0;
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 && mass[i] == mass[max])
            max = i;
        else if (mass[i]> mass[max])
            max = i;// ищем номер максимального элемента
        if (i == 0 && mass[i] == mass[min])
            min = i;
        else if (mass[i] < mass[min])
            min = i;// ищем номер минимального элемента

    }
    std::cout << "min = " << min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "max = " << max << std::endl;
    int proizvedenie = 1;
    if (max < min)
    {
        for (int i = max + 1; i < min; i++)
            proizvedenie *= mass[i];// производим умножение в заданном диапазоне  
    }
    else if (min < max)
    {
        for (int i = min + 1; i < max; i++)
            proizvedenie *= mass[i];
    }
    std::cout << proizvedenie;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Работает]

Comment: если сначала написать максимальный елемент, то оно не считает

Comment: @ДашаНовикова, попробуйте поиграть значениями, например поставьте `max = n-1;` вместо нуля. Экспериментируйте.

Comment: @ДашаНовикова, вот с небольшими изменениями.

Answer (score 0):

**Расчеты на "все случаи жизни" :)**

Код ищет один и более одного результата, если таковые имеются. После поиска - есть примеры сортировки результатов по различным критериям.

Онлайн версия тут - http://ideone.com/4CGmoo

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Ищем произведение элементов массива, которые расположены между 
// максимальным и минимальным элементами
//
// Дополнительно (чего не уточнено в задании):
// 
// 1. Не ищем в обратном порядке (от минимального к максимальному)
// 2. Возможные варианты заносим в вектор результатов и их 
//    разновсячески сортируем в порядке нужного
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef std::pair<std::size_t,std::size_t> PairType;
typedef std::vector<PairType> ResType;

void FuncMul(std::vector<int> Vec, ResType &Res) {
  // в векторе длиной меньше 3-х искать нечего  
  if (Vec.size()<3) throw std::runtime_error("ничего не найдено");
  // определяемся с минимумами и максимумами
  auto Min = *std::min_element(Vec.begin(),Vec.end());    
  auto Max = *std::max_element(Vec.begin(),Vec.end());
  // ищем все пары мах-min
  std::size_t I = 0, S = Vec.size(), X;   
  int M = 0;  
  while(I<S) {
    if (M == 0) {
      if (Vec[I]==Max) { M=1; X=I; }    
    } else {
      if (Vec[I]==Min) { 
        if (I>X+1) Res.push_back({X,I}); 
        M=0;
      } else if (Vec[I]==Max) X=I;
    }
    I++;  
  }
  if(Res.size()<1) throw std::runtime_error("ничего не найдено");
}    

int main() {
  std::vector<int> Vec = {3,-4,1,3,4,9,1,-4,9,9,2,-3,-4,9,1};
  ResType Res;
  try {  
    FuncMul(Vec,Res);
    // лямбда вывода на печать  
    auto PrnPair = [&](const PairType &P) { 
      std::cout << P.first << ":" << P.second << " = " <<
      std::accumulate(Vec.begin()+P.first+1, Vec.begin()+P.second, 1, std::multiplies<int>()) <<        
      std::endl;  
    };
    // лямбда сортировки по величине произведения
    auto SortMul = [&] (const PairType &P1, const PairType &P2) {
      return std::accumulate(Vec.begin()+P1.first+1, Vec.begin()+P1.second, 1, std::multiplies<int>()) <       
             std::accumulate(Vec.begin()+P2.first+1, Vec.begin()+P2.second, 1, std::multiplies<int>());
    };  
    // лямбда сортировки по количеству множимых  
    auto SortDis = [&] (const PairType &P1, const PairType &P2) {
      return P1.second - P1.first < P2.second-P2.first;
    };  
    // 1) печать "сырого" несортированного результата --------------------------------------------
    for(const auto &i:Res) PrnPair(i); 
    std::cout << "=========================" << std::endl;
    // 2) печать отсортированного результата по возрастанию величины произведения ----------------
    std::sort(Res.begin(),Res.end(),SortMul);
    for(const auto &i:Res) PrnPair(i); 
    std::cout << "=========================" << std::endl;  
    // 3) печать отсортированного результата по убыванию количества элементов в произведении ----
    std::sort(Res.begin(),Res.end(),SortDis);
    for(const auto &i:Res) PrnPair(i); 
    std::cout << "=========================" << std::endl;    
  } catch(std::runtime_error &E) {
    std::cout << "Ошибка: " << E.what() << std::endl;  
  } catch(...) {
    std::cout << "Ошибка: что-то пошло не так!" << std::endl;    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int FuncMul(std::vector<int> Vec) {
  if (Vec.size()>2) {
    std::sort(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), std::less<int>());
    return std::accumulate(Vec.begin()+1, Vec.end()-1, 1, std::multiplies<int>());
  }   
  return 0; 
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> Vec = {9,1,2,3,4,1,1,-4};
  std::cout << "FuncMul: " << FuncMul(Vec);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"которые расположены между"_ - сортировка не соответствует условию.

Comment: про сортировку ничего не сказано, а раз не нельзя - значит можно

Comment: @Majestio, Вы серьезно ? Нужно найти значение для текущего порядка, а не для того, который получится после сортировки. Поэтому ни о какой сортировке не может быть и речи.

Comment: Тогда укажите это в вопросе, что порядок важен.

Comment: @Majestio, поймите, акцент и ставится на том, чтобы найти в входном множестве тот самый минимальный и максимальный элемент - при этом возможны различные варианты их расположения, что и осложняет задачу. А так, она становится гораздо более примитивной.

Comment: Вот про варианты - надо было бы в условии задачи более подробно расписать. Обязательно или от максимального к минимальному искать, или "направление" неважно. Что делать если в векторе несколько "отрезков", соотв. задаче? Искать первый произвольный? С большим произведением, с меньшим?

Comment: @isnullxbh ... и да ... во **множестве** позиции элемента не существует, позиция может быть в векторе/массиве. А набор он и есть набор.

Comment: @Majestio, во-первых - в самом задании говорится о массиве, во-вторых - Вы можете сколько угодно придираться к моим словам и рассказывать мне о том, что в контексте множества не существует понятия "позиции" - от этого _не поменяется_ мое мнение о том, что в подобного рода задачах выполнять сортировку - неуместно, и в-третьих, коль уж Вы заговорили про "отрезки" - Ваше решение полностью игнорирует их как фактор, влияющий на решение задачи. На этом мое участие в данном диалоге заканчивается, я хотел сделать Вам замечание - я его сделал. Как к нему относится - дело Ваше.